How to uninstall partially installed package with poetry?
I tried installing a package with poetry for the first time. It worked on a machine and failed on another because the hardware is not compatible with TensorFlow. I should have installed in a virtual environment, but didn't. I tried uninstalling with poetry remove and poetry uninstall and neither exist. I also searched online and found no results.
How can I uninstall everything that poetry installed for this failed package?

Provided that you actually installed the package with Poetry, either via poetry add or using a pyproject.toml file, then poetry remove should work as expected.
Since you mention:

I should have installed in a virtual environment, but didn't.

When running poetry install (with a preexisting pyproject.toml file) or poetry init (from the scratch), first a virtual environment is initialized by default in /.venv, under the current working directory. Then, the dependencies referenced in the lock file are installed. In short, if you installed it using Poetry, you are already using a virtual environment per se.
Perhaps you installed the package via pip without invoking Poetry, in that case the dependency would not be found when trying to use the remove command.

Quick example of the workflow
These two commands will create a new pyproject.toml file, create the virtual environment, add the new dependency (pyjokes in this example), and update the lock file.
poetry init -n
poetry add pyjokes

The show command can now print the mentioned dependency:
poetry show

To remove it, as explained above, simply run:
poetry remove pyjokes


I just tried this: I set up a virtual environment to install pipx and poetry, then changed directory to the current project and ran poetry install. It succeeds without issues. I do not see any venv directory under the project folder. I run poetry remove and get an error: Not enough arguments (missing: "packages"). I run poetry remove . or poetry remove <project-name> and get an error The following packages were not found: <project-name>.

Hi @emonigma, sorry for the late reply! The remove command removes a package from the current list of installed packages, not the entire project. In short, it requires you to specify at least one of the dependencies. To experiment a bit, in the directory where you ran poetry install, you can use poetry show to see one of the dependencies. Then you may choose any of them and try to remove it with poetry remove <WHATEVER_DEPENDENCY>. That should work :)
Also, it should create the .venv folder (that's the default behavior). Could you check if all the hidden files are shown? (ls -a)

I confirm that I don't have .venv in the folder where I installed the package. I can see a list of dependencies with poetry show (even without activating the virtual environment that I created for pipx), for example zipp and tensorflow. The first throws: The following packages were not found: zipp. The second runs, but it installs the package instead of uninstalling TensorFlow and I see at the end: `- Installing x-transformers (1.30.0)
Writing lock file`.
